# javascript function is adding data to screen but then being overridden by another function

Tags: javascript

My issue is related a function being invoked when a page is loaded, which removes the data returned by another function.

**My issue** 
After an order is placed, the user inputs how much they wish to pay, following which their change will be calculated and displayed on the screen. I am able to see the amount of change due when I 
 `console.log(pay - rounded_total)` (See JS code at end of post below).

However when I try change the div as opposed to logging to the console `document.getElementById('change_due').innerHTML = (pay - rounded_total);` it only remains on the screen for a matter of milliseconds before it disappears when the GET request is made again. I am sure this is because a get request is being triggered each time the document has loaded, so ideally I am wondering how best to structure my code to deal with this. I have played around with the code I currently have in every possible way at this stage, but still cannot fix the issue.

I am also aware that my class names should not begin with numbers, however my aim with this program is to improve my vanilla javascript, and get to terms with scope etc. in JS.

My code is as follows:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
         </head>
         <body>
          <ul id="orderList">
             <p class="4.75">Cafe Latte price = 4.75</p>
             <p class="4.75">Flat White price = 4.75</p>
             <p class="3.85">Cappucino price = 3.85</p>
          </ul>
             <div id="total_paid">Amount due: $0.00</div>
             <div id="change_due"></div>

         <form onsubmit="changeDue()">
             <input type="text" id="uniqueID" />
             <input type="submit">
         </form>
         <script src="js/getData.js"></script>
         </body>
        </html>
```

My JS code is as follows:

```
var rounded_total;
var change;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  loadJSONDoc();
});

function loadJSONDoc()
{
  var answer;
  var xmlhttp;

  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    answer = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)

    var items = answer[0].prices[0];
    var total = 0;

    for(var index in items) {

      var node = document.getElementById("orderList");
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      var price = items[index];
      p.setAttribute("class", price)
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(index + " price = $" + price);
      p.appendChild(textnode);
      node.appendChild(p);
      };
    }
    var total = 0;
    var update = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for(var i=0; i< update.length; ++i) {
    update[i].onclick = function() {
    var num = parseFloat(this.className).toFixed(2);
    num = parseFloat(num)
    total += num;
    rounded_total = Math.round(total*100)/100;
    document.getElementById("total_paid").innerHTML = rounded_total;
  }
}

}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/items",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function changeDue(){
  var pay = document.getElementById('uniqueID').value;
  document.getElementById('change_due').innerHTML = (pay - rounded_total);
};
```

Again, to be clear on what I looking to implement, is that when a user has chosen their desired items, they then enter an amount into the input box, following which they submit will provide the amount of change due.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to fix this. But i am not able to understand as why you are using form post here and that too without the url?

you can update

```
function changeDue(){
 ...
 return false; // this is avoid form submission
}
```

or

```
function changeDue(event){
 ...
 // you can also use event.preventDefault() or stopPropagation() here. one of them should work.
}
```

But again both will stop the form from getting submitted to the server. When you will submit the form to the server, the current page will be refreshed and output of the form request will be displayed on the screen. Thats the reason why you are seeing it for a fraction of second. because your code updates the div and then form submit refreshes the page.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense. I better look for an alternative way of getting user input besides using a form then. thanks @Vikash

Comment: you can use form to get user input but you need to handle form submit event accordingly. Otherwise it will submit the form on getting submit event. instead of submit button you can use input type button. and use onclick to call your js function. that way you dont have to do what i said before.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks. Some basics caught me out regarding the submitting of the form, but this question and your answer has taught me the difference between submitting a form and a button. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest you from good will nothing personal. Try to rewrite your code as I understand You are trying to success something with very very wrong structure.

Anyway You can try this or something similar...

```
     function stopPost()
         {
             if (//something - you can skip if clause)
             {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 return false;
             }
          }
```